# Convert all string in double quotes in one quotes use RegExp PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Please help for regexp.

I have, example, next string:

```
var image = "<div class='test'>Hello. It's div.</div>" + "<div class='test2'></div>";
var f = function(test){alert("error: "+test)}
```

I need convert it with php to

```
var image = '<div class="test">Hello. It\'s div.</div>' + '<div class="test2"></div>';
var f = function(test){alert('error: '+test)}
```

And this string is example...

I not understand how create normal replace...

**UPD**:
For example, If I have

```
var a = "asdb'dsaa'fdsfd";
var b = 'dsad"dsadsa"dsadas';
```

Then me need

```
var a = 'asdb\'dsaa\'fdsfd';
var b = 'dsad"dsadsa"dsadas';
```

Comment: What did you try so far? You might want to use `str_replace` instead of RegEx.

Comment: Did you forget the conversion of ```'test2'``` or am only I confused?

Comment: How do you know to convert into `"` or `\'` as in your example? What is the rule?

Comment: Sorry, It's miss click... I need "" or \' in inner quotes

Comment: Why `'test'` becomes `"test"` and `It's` becomes `It\'s` ? What are the rules?

Answer (score 0):

I know this look wierd but here you go:

```
$var = 'var image = "<div class=\'test\'>Hello. It\'s div.</div>" + "<div class=\'test2\'></div>";
var f = function(test){alert("error: "+test)}';


$var = str_replace("DUMMY_PLACEHOLDER", "'", str_replace("'", '"', str_replace('"', 'DUMMY_PLACEHOLDER', $var)));

echo $var;
```

And more readable version:

```
$var = 'var image = "<div class=\'test\'>Hello. It\'s div.</div>" + "<div class=\'test2\'></div>";
var f = function(test){alert("error: "+test)}';

$var = str_replace('"', 'DUMMY_PLACEHOLDER', $var);
$var = str_replace("'", '"', $var);
$var = str_replace("DUMMY_PLACEHOLDER", "'", $var);

echo $var;
```

Comment: No, I need all string in one quotes, but if this string have quotes in double qoutes - I need convert quotes to doubke quotes